# Displaying a hidden element after a set duration

Tags: jquery

I am planning to have the image in the `div` shown below to initially be hidden, but displayed about 1200ms after the page loads.

However, it isn't working. My jQuery should be wrong somewhere ..

HTML:

```
<div id="zz">
    <img src='images/number2.png' />
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#zz').hide().delay(1200).fadeIn('normal');

</script>
```

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zf9nz/. You remembering to load jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct (assuming you are using jQuery 1.4 or later - delay() was added in 1.4). What is likely happening is that you are calling your script before the DOM has finished loading?

Try wrapping your call like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#zz').hide().delay(1200).fadeIn('normal');
});
```

Comment: Yes you're right, apparently I called my script before the DOM finished loading. Adding the `$(document).ready(function()` code makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the div via CSS, not jquery. Then use the rest of your jquery statement without the hide command.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/uxT9Y/)

Comment: hiding via CSS is simply more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of hiding it via CSS. No harm learning new methods to doing the same thing.